# Does Geoname web service has a limitation on requests?

Tags: geolocation

Can anyone tell me if the Geoname web service, which provides the address and lat/long information, has a limitation on requests? e.g. 2,500 hits per day. Cause I found that Google Maps API allows 2,500 hits per day.

Thanks very much.

Yours,
Ling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI all,

I foudn the hidden answer in the link http://www.geonames.org/export/, hope that might be useful for you.